# Suggestions to start Statistical Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, statistics, differential-geometry, book-recommendation, stochastic-geometry

I am a computer science PhD student, and I need statistical manifolds theory for my work. I am currently reading Differential Geometry of Curves and Surface by Kristopher Tapp and Carmo. I plan to study Lee's smooth Manifold next. (My supervisor's recommendations.)

Unfortunately I do not have the topology background to the depth I would like to have to; I studied Topology without Tears in my second year (not completely) but I do not remember all of what I read either. But I am keeping it alongside.

Can anyone suggest a self-readable set of books to get to Stat. Manifold? I might end up needing quite a bit of Discrete Differential Geometry as well. Other suggestions about alternate study plans are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try *Information Geometry and Its Applications*, by Shun-ichi Amari. He pretty much founded the field, and in this book he doesn't really assume any background on smooth manifolds.

Another option is *Information Geometry*, by Ay, Jost, Le, and Schwachhofer, but the mathematics there is much more rigorous than in Amari's book.

For something quicker, look up *An Elementary Introduction to Information Geometry*: it is a 61-page review by Frank Nielsen, published on 'entropy'.

Comment: Is there a book that can bridge the gaps that I need to in Measure theoretic Probability? I found a few books, but some are very daunting and have material I might not need.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really help further with this. I am not a specialist in Information Geometry or Probability -- I'm just aware of some standard references like the ones in this answer in case I ever need something from the area or decide to work on a project related to it...